# code in jmeter using BeanShellPostProcessor Scripting

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have to write if statement in Jmeter using BeanShellPostProcessor scripting. I have to take the value of statuscode from response, if statuscode is 100 then print the value of status as 'Pass' in csv file otherwise 'Fail'. I have written a code but it is not working. Please help me

```
StatusCode=vars.get("StatusCode");
Status=vars.get("Status");

log.info(Status);
log.info(StatusCode);

f = new FileOutputStream("D:/result1.csv",true);
p=new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
if (StatusCode=100)
 {
    Status="Pass";
 }else
 {
    Status="Fail";
 }
print(StatusCode + " ," + Status);
f.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you printed Status and Status code in Logs, so are you able to see the values in logs?

If yes,
Then just change your if condition to

```
if (StatusCode.equals("100"))
```

Comment: hey thanks for ur response .... I was getting the value of status code in my result file but after I added this if statement . the code is not working

Comment: have you tried with the condition which i have provided?